# How to use custom/non-default tf.Graph in Tensorflow the correct way?

Tags: python, session, graph, parallel-processing, tensorflow

I'm very new to `Tensorflow` and I am reading [https://www.amazon.com/TensorFlow-Machine-Learning-Cookbook-McClure/dp/1786462168](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786462168). One argument that I have noticed in `tf.Session` is `graph`.  I like having full control of the flow and I was wondering **how to properly use the `tf.Graph` with `tf.Session` and how to add computations to a specific graph?** Also, what is the canonical syntax, if any, in which people add operations to a specific graph in `Tensorflow`?

Analogous to the below:

```
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=t, y=np.sin(t))
```

compared to:

```
plt.scatter(x=t, y=np.sin(t))
```

How can I have this same flexibility with `tf.Graph()`?

```
G = tf.Graph()

t_query = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
pH_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=t_query.shape)

def simple_sinewave(t, name=None):
    return tf.sin(t, name=name)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    r = sess.run(simple_sinewave(pH_t), feed_dict={pH_t:t_query})
# array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.27877161e-01,   2.53654599e-01,
# ...
#         -1.27877384e-01,   1.74845553e-07], dtype=float32)
```

Now trying it with specifying a `graph` argument:

```
with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
    r = sess.run(simple_sinewave(pH_t), feed_dict={pH_t:t_query})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-d73a1f0963e3> in <module>()
     26 #         -1.27877384e-01,   1.74845553e-07], dtype=float32)
     27 with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
---> 28     r = sess.run(simple_sinewave(pH_t), feed_dict={pH_t:t_query})
```

...
    RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().

### Update using [David Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4790871/david-parks) answer with this problem:

```
# Custom Function
def simple_sinewave(t, name=None):
    return tf.sin(t, name=name)

# Synth graph
G = tf.Graph()

# Build Graph
with G.as_default():
    t_query = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
    pH_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=t_query.shape)

# Run session using Graph
with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
    r = sess.run(simple_sinewave(pH_t), feed_dict={pH_t:t_query})
r
# array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.27877161e-01,   2.53654599e-01,
#          3.75266999e-01,   4.90717560e-01,   5.98110557e-01,
# ...
#         -4.90717530e-01,  -3.75267059e-01,  -2.53654718e-01,
#         -1.27877384e-01,   1.74845553e-07], dtype=float32)
```

**Bonus: Is there a specific nomenclature for naming placeholder variables in Tensorflow? Like `pd.DataFrame` as `df_data`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally do it this way:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  # build your model
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(...)
```

I use multiple graphs sometimes for running a test set separately from the training set, which is similar to your example above, you would do:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  # build your model
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(...)
```

As you also pointed out, you can avoid using `with` and just do `sess = tf.Session(graph=g)`, and you'd have to close your session yourself. Most use cases will be simplified by using python's `with`

When you have two graphs, you're setting each `as_default()` as the default graph, whenever you're working with that graph.

Example:

```
g1 = tf.Graph()
g2 = tf.Graph()

with g1.as_default():
  # do stuff like normal, g1 is the graph that will be used
  with tf.Session() as session_on_g1:
    session_on_g1.run(...)

with g2.as_default():
  # do stuff like normal, g2 is the graph that will be used
  with tf.Session() as session_on_g2:
    session_on_g2.run(...)
```

Comment: Excellent answer @David Parks.  The piece I was missing was the `new_graph_object.as_default()` in the `with` statement.

Comment: That tripped me up the first time I saw it too. :) As for the placeholder variable naming convention, the most common names are `X` and `y`, often `y_` is used for the predicted values of the labels. I'm partial to `y_hat` myself. I've sometimes found it useful to include datatypes and dimensions with my placeholders, so for an image input I might use `imgs_3d_int8` to remind myself that these should be 3D (no batch dimension) images and not yet converted to float32, or `imgs_4d_float32` in another case. I often use `labels` instead of `y`, that's not uncommon to see either.

Comment: That is good to know.  I don't want to develop an esoteric nomenclature for things if there is already one that has been adopted by the community lol.  `y_hat` is a nice one b/c `y_` can easily get overlooked when eye-balling some code. I'm excited to get deep into tf.  I started following the [r/deepdream](https://www.reddit.com/r/deepdream/) reddit thread and got inspired again.  I do ML stuff for ocean microbe datasets but this stuff is just way too tempting to not learn.